# MySQL on VM is not responding to external clients

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, connection, remote-access, rider

I've installed MySQL server on brand new VM with Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

Seems MySQL is not visible. From VM I could access successfully via standard `mysql` command with the same user and password I have tried remotely, but remotely it does not work.

Added port 3306 as enabled to `ufw` firewall, also added rule for 3306 TCP to `iptables`. Checked against local address binding in MySQL config, but there was no such entry. I can access machine via SSH, but not MySQL through same IP address. The user is added for `%` addresses with standard authentication with password. All privileges also granted.

Tried with `jdbc` provider from JetBrains Rider IDE - `Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

Tried with MySql Shell - `ArgumentError: X protocol error: MySQL server has gone away Classic protocol error: MySQL Error 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Any suggestions what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: FIRST STEP: ensure "mysql" command works.  Both locally (on the VM guest), and remotely (on your physical host).  The first thing to check mysqld.conf, per JollyRoger's [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74737338/421195) below.  The next thing (if it still doesn't work) is to check your VM software's networking.  For example, VMWare has "host-only", "bridged"  and "NAT".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your MySQL is only listening on localhost

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

search for the bind-address parameter, change 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0
and restart the mysql deamon

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```